# Tool for code Navigation in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, ctags, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to study and modify a big and poorly documented codebase written in pl/sql. I use Oracle SQL Developer to navigate through it, but it become tedious because there is not a "go to declaration" nor "find usages" option so I have to go manually to the referred package to find the function or procedure I want to understand, or grep an offline copy to find the usages.

I have tried to setup vim+ctags, but exuberant ctags gets confused by case insensitiviness.

So the question is, which tools allow to easily navigate through PL/SQL code?

Comment: dbForge Studio for Oracle supports navigation between language constructs.  [Manage PL/SQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/plsql-developer-tools.html#document-outline) with [Document Outline window](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/images/document-outline.png)

Comment: If the "case insensitiviness" is the reason ctags gets confused, fixing it may be easy. Fixing is not promised but it's worth reporting to https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues with an example input.

Answer (score 4):

[PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html), from Allround Automations has some nice features to navigate through code. You can download and install a full-feature trial version that will last you one month. Afterwards, if you like the tool and want to go on using it, you will have to pay a (modest) fee.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Tobys PLSQL Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plsqleditor/). It gives you:

- Syntax highlighting
- F3 jump to code
- Package outlines
- Code completion
- Compile to database with error highlighting
- Auto header generation using PLDoc

I'm still searching for a good tool to look at dependencies. You can query the data dictionary to find package dependencies but it doesn't go down to the level of procedures/functions within the packages themselves or line numbers within each package.

Answer (score 2):

[Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) is able to generate ctags documents for PL/SQL stored procedures, and there are tons of editors which can read the tags back, including such classics as Emacs and vi.  I personally use it with Sublime Text 2 working on big 3000+ line stored procedure definitions.  (ST2 is a great all-around editor, but not particularly better than any other editor for editing SQL, it has basic code highlighting and that's all.)

The only problem I've got with Exuberant's tags is that it will only generate a single tag entry even if it sees the definitions more than once, so that if you put your package declaration and your package body in the same file, the tags will only jump you to the first entry (usually the declaration).

Answer (score 1):

I have recently switched from Oracle's [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) to Quest's [TOAD](http://www.toadsoft.com/toad_oracle.htm) and I love it ! What I like most about TOAD is the [debuging](http://www.toadworld.com/Default.aspx?tabid=67&EntryID=82) tool. The capabilities I use can be found in both products but TOAD to me is a little easier to use, but SQL Developer is "free".

Comment: As the OP, I cannot find any "find usages" feature in TOAD, either. So please let me know if you know if it is available.

Answer (score 1):

See the [SD Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) for a tool which does searches far faster than grep over large bodies of source code, by preindexing the source code.  The Search Engine is language sensitive, so you can form queries in terms of langauge identifiers, numbers, keywords, and operators.  Whitespace and comments don't fool it.

It works for PL/SQL as well as many other languages (C, C++, C#, COBOL, Java, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I export my PL/SQL-Packages from the database into the file system for version control (I use Git). The packages (body and specification) are all within the same directory.
I edit the package with Visual Studio Code (currently version 1.53.2), because VS Code has a great support for Git.

A right click on a procedure opens the context menu and `Go to definition`(or F12) jumps to the procedure even if it was declared in another package.

You jump back by clicking on the menu Go --> Back (or Alt+LeftArrow).

Comment: For syntax highlight for PL/SQL files I used the VS Code extension xyz.plsql-language

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains' DataGrip is another option. You can navigate from the package function spec to its implementation in the body by clicking the icon next to the function name. Its experience is very similar to Oracle SQLDeveloper.